# Answer a call programmatically

Tags: java, android, call

I've searched through a lot of topics, and I know my question was asked before. I'm writing an aplication that overrides default incoming call application. There is no good solution, yet the best one I've found is to use

```
    Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(
            KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown,
            "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

    Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(
            KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp,
            "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
```

But it's not working all the time. Another one using telephony service is not working for android versions 2.3+. I wonder how applications like [Ultimate Call Screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lowveld.ucs&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5sb3d2ZWxkLnVjcyJd) answers a call. Any ideas?

Comment: Wow I'm glad I don't use an android, if they allow apps to interfere with calls this easily.

Comment: Wow, I'm glad I don't use iOS if they don't allow me to do what I want with my own hardware.  I can think of at least a dozen good reasons an app could want to do this.  For example, automatically answer the phone from a voice command while driving

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer/AutoAnswerIntentService.java

They cheat by calling the bluetooth service and faking that someone hit the pickup button on a handset.

Comment: My code above is from their example, it's working 70% of time, unfortunately it's not 100% raliable